# git diff without changes of single quotes to double quotes

Tags: git

One of my colleagues applied results of js-linting, so there is a huge part of diff now where all that's actually changed on a line is just single quotes `'` to double quotes `"`

```
- var mod = require('mod');
+ var mod = require("mod");
```

is there any way to filter it out of `git diff`? If something else changed on a line, it should still be displayed:

```
- var mod = require('mod1');
+ var mod = require("mod2");
```

Comment: Check out the `--word-diff-regex=<regex>` option

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this using just `git diff`. You might be able to do something by piping output of `git diff` to `sed` to remove those lines out of the output.

Comment: You could have instead made two commits, one for the quotes only change, and the other for those functional changes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen these are not my commits, I must review them though

Comment: I understand.  Just saying for future reference if you can separate the cosmetic changes from the actual changes, you might avoid this.

Comment: @neuhaus could you explain in a bit more details? I gave it a couple of tries but it doesn't seem to work, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @xaxa it was just a guess, not sure if it works. you're on your own

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a great way to do this, especially when you consider that changes between `"` and `'` *could* be bugs.

```
"hello" => 'hello'
```

may be fine, but

```
"what's up" => 'what's up'
```

would be concerning (level of concerning perhaps varying by language).

You could use `--word-diff-regex` to treat `'` and `"` as "not part of words"; in that case **all** `'` and `"` characters would be ignored in calculating the diff.  However, this performs a "word" diff rather than the typical line-oriented diff.  For example

```
$ git diff file1

diff --git a/file1 b/file1
index 64315fd..cd80abf 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file1
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-"this is a test"
-"this is a changing test"
-"this couldn't cause a problem, could it?"
-"it's possible some edits could be trouble"
+'this is a test'
+'this is a changing line of test'
+'this couldn't cause a problem, could it?'
+'it"s possible some edits could be trouble'"'"''
```

Well, that's not much use; it just says everything changed.  Ok, how about

```
$ git diff --word-diff-regex="[^'\"]" file1
diff --git a/file1 b/file1
index 64315fd..cd80abf 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file1
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
'this is a test'
'this is a changing {+line of +}test'
'this couldn't cause a problem, could it?'
'it"s possible some edits could be trouble'"'"''
```

Well, it detected and highlighted the change on the 2nd line, so that's good.  (This doesn't come through in the copied text, but by default on the console the addition would be highlighted green, so it does call the changes out reasonably well.)  It doesn't notice that I've changed line 3 in a potentially destructive way, and it didn't notice a bunch of spurious quote changes (and additions) on line 4.

So it's not perfect.

You could get slightly better results by pre-processing the file, forcing both versions to use a normalized quote notation; that would catch line 4 above, but still not line 3.  And you'd no longer be directly diffing the source-controlled versions, so what you do isn't quite as auditable so to speak.

Comment: This looks like what I need, thanks! I'll test a bit more and come back to accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround.

Suppose you have your original version in commit `A` and the version to be reviewed in commit `B` where you want to find out if the only change is the result of applying the linter, or if there's more.

Create a branch based on `A` and run the linter yourself, resulting in a commit `A'`:

```
o -- o -- A -- B   # version to be reviewed
           \
            A'     # version with only linting applied
```

Now generate the diff between `A'` and `B`. You should only see any changes that were *not* the result of running the linter.

Comment: That's smart! but unfortunately I can't run linter myself

Comment: Maybe you can ask the colleagues who produced `B` to do it for you. But then on the other hand you can simply ask them to produce separate commits in the first place, as Tim Biegeleisen suggested.

Comment: I tried that, however sometimes lines with linting changes happened on the lines adjacent to the lines in which things were actually changed. That caused `patch` to be unable to apply the diff between the linted main branch and the linted feature branch to the original main branch.